# postgresql: Change timestamp timezone part without shifting hours?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a timestamp field in my table that has stored the data in UTC-10. However, the correct timezone is UTC+10

I would like to change the timezone part to UTC+10 without shifting the  hours. Only want the system to consider the same timestamp as UTC+10 instead of UTC-10

If I do it like

```
select email_timestamp as time zone 'UTC+10' from emails
```

then it also shift the hours.

Can someone please tell me how to change the timezone part without shifting the hours?

Comment: *"I have a timestamp field in my table that has stored the data in UTC-10."* PostgreSQL doesn't store timestamps that way. If you declared the column to be of type `timestamp with time zone`, "[the internally stored value is always in UTC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)".

Comment: Please, provide: `CREATE TABLE` for your table (timestamp column in particular), sample data found in the table and the result that you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

Strip off the time zone without changing the time, then add a timezone without converting the time:

```
(myfield::timestamp || 'UTC+10')::timestamptz
```

Select it again for your timezone to see that's what you wanted:

```
SELECT myfield AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+10'
```

Comment: "ERROR:  invalid input syntax . . ."